# Grunt Wiredep not injecting Foundation css

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, wiredep

I have foundation in my bower_components through bower (bower install foundation).

I also have grunt-wiredep in my Gruntfile.js as shown below:

```
    wiredep: {
      dev: {
       src: ['<%= FILE_PATHS.client %>/index.html']
      }
    }
```

Also, I have on my index.html

```
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
```

After running grunt wiredep:dev, foundation.js is injected, but not foundation.css or foundation.scss

Am I missing something with wiredep configuration? It seems to pick up font-awesome.css, but not for foundation?

Is this issue similar to the latest version of Bootstrap http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/06/15/bootstrap-3-3-5-released/

Comment: did you try overriding?

Comment: Yes, it did work. I should have tried it before posting. Thanks for your help tho! @Sudheer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I should have tried this first, but similar to bootstrap, I needed to add an override particularly for foundation.

```
    "overrides": {
      "foundation": {
        "main": [
        "css/foundation.css",
        "js/foundation.js"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Thanks, Sudheer for your suggestion.